# What is "Kerberos" and why does it have a notification page on my Mac after installing Monterey?

Tags: macos, notifications, monterey

I just installed macOS Monterey on my 2018 Mac mini and noticed after toying around with the settings that something called "Kerberos" is coming up as one of the items allowed to send notifications in the notification settings. What is this, why is it here after not having been previously, is it malware, and if so, how do I get rid of it? Never seen this before so not sure why it's here now.

Comment: This may be help you : https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kerberos_(protocol)

Answer (score 1):

[Kerberos](https://web.mit.edu/kerberos/) is a Single-Sign On (SSO) extension. Apple uses it to allow users to replace many different passwords by a single one.

Here are the full details, from the horse's mouth : [apple doc](https://support.apple.com/guide/deployment/kerberos-single-sign-on-extension-depe6a1cda64/web)